# How to place ASP.NET custom controls in separate tab panels?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, tabs, custom-controls, placeholder

I have a asp.net placeholder which gets populated with many custom controls, each custom control is a summary of a location containing various facts and interactions.

When directly populating the placeholder with the controls they get added one under another down the page.

I'm trying to find a way to place each custom control generated in a loop in its own tab (any sort of tab, asp.net/jquery ui etc) so that the user can select the summary they wish to view instead of having to scroll down the page to find it.

Does anyone have any inkling of how this might be accomplished? (I'm using ASP.NET and VB.NET)

Answer (score 0):

You have several options asp.net Ajax Toolkit offers a Tab Control, Accordion both great additions, then of course you have jquery that offers tabs aswell.

Asp.net Ajax tabs [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Tabs/Tabs.aspx)

Asp.net Accordion [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Accordion/Accordion.aspx)

Jquery UI Tabs [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Comment: I'm not asking after Tab controls, I'm looking for a way to populate any tab control with a dynamic number of generated custom controls.

Comment: if you have user controls for each "tab" then why would you need to populate dynamically? you just put each user control inside each tab and it'll display.  Maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly. It would help if you specified exactly what the end result you are looking for is.

Comment: The controls are generated in a loop which currently adds each control to a placeholder, each iteration I want to add the control produced to a different tab.

Comment: Do you have different placeholders already in your aspx or are you creating them on the fly?

Comment: Currently I just have one placeholder in the aspx to which all the custom controls are added, because if I created them on the fly, I can't then add controls to them during the same event because they wouldn't yet exist.